# How to limit the clone of forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have a 4 form which has a button below it saying add more experience and add more education etc, when user clicks on the add more button the jquery creates a clone of the form and append it, the problem i'm getting is I'm not able to limit the number of clones here is code

```
$(".btn-duplicator").on("click", function(a) {
      a.preventDefault();

      var b = $(this).parent().siblings(".duplicateable-content"),
          c = $("<div>").append(b.clone()).html();
       $(c).insertBefore(b);
      var d = b.prev(".duplicateable-content");
          d.fadeIn(600).removeClass("duplicateable-content"), d.find(".btn-remove").on("click", function(a) {
          a.preventDefault();
      var b = $(this).parents(".item-block").parent("div");
          b.fadeOut(600, function() {
             b.remove()
                })
            })

        });
```

i tried addding

```
var count = 1;
    if(count < 5) {
    count++;
    }
```

but nothing seems to work how can i limit the cloning to only 5 forms

html structure for experience

```
<div class="col-xs-12 duplicateable-content">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-duplicator">Add experience</button>
</div>
```

structure for education & more

```
<div class="col-xs-12 duplicateable-content">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-duplicator">Add Education</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `var count=1` depends on where you declare it.

If you declare `var count` inside click handler it will always be set to one each click. If you declare it outside click handler it will increment.

```
var count = 1; // will work
$(".btn-duplicator").on("click", function(a) {
    var count = 1; // won't work - is same value every click
```

Can also count elements

```
if( $(".duplicateable-content").length >=5 ){
   alert('Only allowed 5');
   return;// don't proceed to clone code
}
```

Comment: what if there are more than one button, i mean what if my page consist of two or three add more button - like add experience, add education

Comment: Shouldn't matter...same event handler, same `count` variable or if count elements in dom would be same total assuming classes are all same for each common type of element

Comment: it matters because i used your second method if( $(".duplicateable-content").length >=5 ) and when i clicked on add more it said only allowed 5 on its first click

Comment: well i'm not sure what your html looks like. I assumed there would only be 5 of those allowed total in page. How many are there?

Comment: See, i have a page where there are 3 forms each form has a div btn-duplicator & when i click on add more button it clone the form above it, according to you what could be the best way to limit it

Comment: why wasn't that important part mentioned in question to begin with? Please update question with all relevant details and html structure

Comment: Note that very beginning of question says ***"I have a form"***..... that doesn't imply multiple sets of forms

Comment: Assuming they are all wrapped in containers you can count within each container `$(this).closest('.form-container').find(".duplicateable-content").length`

Comment: So does each set have a parent container? One main container for each type in other words

Comment: <div class="row"> this is the parent

Comment: So try `closest()` I wrote above and make the class `row` ....closest('.row')` . Unless You use row inside also in case give them a special class like I already used above in `closest()`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following after:

```
$(".btn-duplicator").on("click", function(a) {
  var noClones = $(this).data('clones') || 0;
  $(this).data('clones', ++noClones);
  if (noClones > 5) return;
  // ...
  // ...
```

Comment: Note: Assumes only one such button exists or `data('clones')` will be different across different buttons